# How to Evaluate a Cell written in code and store the result in a variable

Tags: evaluation

Consider the following command.

`CellPrint[Cell["[1,2,3]", "ExternalLanguage"]]`

It creates a python cell with command `[1,2,3]`.

If evaluated then the result is `{1,2,3}`

Is there a way to Evaluate the cell expression programmatically and get the result in a variable. Like following,

`result=CellEvaluate[Cell["[1,2,3]", "ExternalLanguage"]];`

So now the `result` variable contains `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Why not just use `ExternalEvalute`?

Comment: Because it is currently not connected with ExternalLanguage Cells. If you define some function in ExternalLanguage Cells and use `ExternalEvaluate["Python","..."]` then this does not have access to those definitions since they both use different kernel session of python. This is a bug which is confirmed to be fixed in 12.0 but i want some workaround now.

Comment: Ah just look into the `CellEvaluationFunction` then. I'll post an answer.

Comment: See also WFR [SetLanguageCellSession](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/SetLanguageCellSession) as used in [236298/61736](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236298/61736)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want to be able to use the same evaluator as the .nb does, so we'll figure out what the .nb does:

```
CurrentValue[
 EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "ExternalLanguage", 
  CellEvaluationFunction}]

FrontEnd`Private`ExternalLanguageCellEvaluationFunction
```

Then look at the `DownValue`:

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal@
 FrontEnd`Private`ExternalLanguageCellEvaluationFunction
```

And we see it just calls this:

```
ExternalEvaluate`FE`ExternalCellEvaluate
```

Which we dig into and get that it's just working off of this `Association`:

```
ExternalEvaluate`FE`$CellSessions
```

And then we use that like so:

```
ExternalEvaluate[ExternalEvaluate`FE`$CellSessions["Python"], "1"]
```

And now you can programmatically access .nb definitions.

Comment: Beautiful ... is there a way to look at the definitions of all builtin functions using `GeneralUtilities`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But you can look at many of them using that function. Some don’t expose their definitions.

Comment: If i apply this function to say `Sin` I see that it says <<kernel function>>. Does it mean that it is not written in the wolfram language so is part of the kernel written in C?

Comment: @user13892 yeah a huge amount of the functionality in Mathematica is actually implemented in C++

Comment: Also if i create a package in which i give the function the attribute `Locked`, `Protected` and `ReadProtected` and then use this GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal on it. Will i be able to see the definitions?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: If possible provide the general solution where i can evaluate the Cell expression and get the result even for those which are not External Language Cells.

Comment: @user13892 not sure what you mean... there don't you just use `ExternalEvaluate`?