# How to set default version for an external language code cell?

Tags: python, default, external-language-cell

This example is for Python but I would like to set this option for any external language.

I have a couple of versions of Python installed.

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Python"][All, "Version"]
```

> [image]

When I create an external language code cell and evaluate code the Python version is not the one I need.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>

```
<Python> 1+1
```

Then

```
Through@Select[ExternalSessions[], #["System"] == "Python" &]@"Version"
```

> ```
> {"3.6.3"}
> ```

However, I would like the Python external code cells to use version 3.8.2.  Where is this option set?  I have not noticed anything it the Edit | Preferences dialogue.

Comment: If you look at ``ExternalEvaluate`FE`ExternalCellEvaluate`` which is how this is implemented, you see that it starts a session via `StartExternalSession[lang]` so you could try to mess with that _or_ you can specify a specific session to use by setting the appropriate key in ``ExternalEvaluate`FE`$CellSessions`` which is an `Association` mapping language names to sessions

Comment: @b3m2a1 That is good information. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be realised by manipulating the registered external bundles.

Based on the OP's scenario, one can simply do the following:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "path/to/python3.8.2"]
```

Then `Python3.8.2` would appear at the top of the external evaluators:

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Python"][All, "Version"]
```

Once the kernel is restarted, the notebook external language cell will default to the 3.8.2 kernel:

```
import sys;(sys.executable, sys.version)
```

Comment: So it is purely the order in which the external evaluators appear in `FindExternalEvaluators`?  I hope WRI adds some settings to Edit | Preferences to control this. (+1)

Comment: @Edmund seems like so; but I fully agree with you that this should be more explicitly customisable or documented.

Answer (score 11):

A `ResourceFunction` called [SetLanguageCellSession](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/SetLanguageCellSession) gives a complete solution for managing external language sessions in Python, Julia, R, etc.

**Basic example:**

[image]

This solution works in 12.1+ and so answers these posts as well:

- ["ExternalLanguage" cell with ExternalSessionObject](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167605/externallanguage-cell-with-externalsessionobject/167634?noredirect=1#comment595031_167634)
- [Use conda env for ExternalLanguage cell?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167872/use-conda-env-for-externallanguage-cell)

Comment: This is cool! How'd you get around this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167605/externallanguage-cell-with-externalsessionobject/167634?noredirect=1#comment595031_167634

Comment: @b3m2a1 I went spelunking through "ExternalEvaluate" private context. Behind the scenes, the external cell will look for the first `ExternalSession` object with the name "DefaultXXXSession" :) Thanks for the reminder, I'll mention this in that question as well.

Comment: Great find. (+1)

Comment: This does not seem to currently work on "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)". In a new notebook I run:
`s = StartExternalSession["Python"]` and then `ResourceFunction[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/mikesollami/DeployedResources/\
Function/SetLanguageCellSession"][s]` as in the example in the documentation. This results in the error `Part 1 of {} does not exist.` followed by more errors.

Comment: @Kvothe that is an old resource, Make sure your have configured a valid python target by doing `pip install pyzmq` and then it should work: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/SetLanguageCellSession

Comment: I have 12.1.1.0 and get an error when try to execute s = ResourceFunction["SetLanguageCellSession"][] Do I need 12.2 for this function to work?

Comment: Before that works you need to do two things 1. "pip install zmq" in the conda environment 2. register the python executable for that env with RegisterExternalEvaluator